# How to get Meta Keywords using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm using Nokogiri for an assignment and I'm struggling to figure this out. It's hurting my brain. Any steps, hints, or examples leading to the solution would be lovely.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is a simple example:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'


doc = Nokogiri::HTML("<html><head><meta name=\"Keywords\" content=\"one, two, three\"></head><body></body></html>")

doc.xpath("//meta[@name='Keywords']/@content").each do |attr|
  puts attr.value
end
```

Comment: since there's only supposed to be one, maybe doc.at('meta[@name="Keywords"]')[:content] makes more sense

Comment: No, wrong. it needs to be case sensitive. metaKeywords = doc.xpath('//meta[case_insensitive_equals(@name,"keywords")]', XpathFunctions.new)[0].attributes["content"].value