# How to extract search meta name within HTML page to extract content using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, asp.net-web-api, httparty

I am trying out Nokogiri and HTTparty to grab a content verification token that's generated in my rails model. This meta tag has a UUID and the user will paste that tag in their index.html file for verification purposes:

Domain Model:

```
class Domain
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String
  field :url, type: String
  field :active, type: Boolean, default: false
  field :verification_token, type: String

  belongs_to :user

  before_create :generate_verification_token

  protected

  def generate_verification_token
    self.verification_token = SecureRandom.hex(30)
  end
end
```

Domain View:

```
<h1><%= @domain.name %></h1>

<p><%= @domain.url %></p>

<% if !@domain.active? %>
<div class="alert alert-danger">
  <strong>Oops!</strong> Your domain is not verified!.
</div>
<div class="lead">
  Please add the following meta tag to your domain root url page
  <pre><%= "<meta name='trackmetrics_verification' content='#{@domain.verification_token}'/>" %></pre>
</div>
<% end %>
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_domain_path(@domain), class: 'btn btn-success' %>
<%= link_to "New Domain", new_domain_path(@domain), class: 'btn btn-success' %>
<p><%= link_to "Back to List", domains_path %></p>
```

Essentially, the user is going to include

```
<meta name='trackmetrics_verification' content='21bd47859ea549244e66a4582e99068fe0bc2063d6276a4426c2c3bb2e15'/>
```

in their root url page(index.html) and I want to have a Verification Controller to check whether the user actually included the meta tag in that page..if they did, their domain will be flagged to True.

My Verification Controller:

```
class VerificationController < ApplicationController

  require 'nokogiri'
  require 'httparty'

  def index
    @domain = Domain.find(params[:Domain_id]) 
    @doc = Nokogiri::HTML(HTTParty.get(@domain.url))
  end

end
```

My question is how would I grab that

```
<meta name='trackmetrics_verification' content='21bd47859ea549244e66a4582e99068fe0bc2063d6276a4426c2c3bb2e15'/>
```

and look for the trackmetrics_verification metaname using Nokogiri?

Would it be something like

```
def index
        @domain = Domain.find(params[:Domain_id]) 
        @doc = Nokogiri::HTML(HTTParty.get(@domain.url))
        if @doc.xpath("//meta[@name ="trackmetrics_verification"]")
           @domain.active = true
           flash[:notice] = "Your domain has been verified!"
       else
           flash[:error] = "Incorrect verification"
       end
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Meta Keywords using Nokogiri?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554053/how-to-get-meta-keywords-using-nokogiri)

Comment: @mus I think it's different..that post is iterating through every meta key word within html doc and capturing them...I am thinking of finding one specific meta and validating that capture with the name...any clues? Thanks :)

Comment: How is that different? Just use your meta name instead of `keywords`.

Comment: @mus so I guess my method is correct? the one I posted up there..I just want some input or perhaps a better way of implementing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XPath you’ve used, `//meta[@name ="trackmetrics_verification"]`, will return any `meta` element nodes that have a `name` attribute of `trackmetrics_verification` (there likely should be only one such node). You want the `content` attribute of this node. One way to get it is to extend the query to specify the attribute:

```
//meta[@name ="trackmetrics_verification"]/@content
```

With Nokogiri, using [`at_xpath`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at_xpath) since you only expect one matching node, you can get the value of the attribute node with the `text` method with:

```
@doc.at_xpath('//meta[@name ="trackmetrics_verification"]/@content').text
```

An alternative with Nokogiri is to select the `meta` node and use the [`[]` method](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-5B-5D) to get the value of the attribute:

```
@doc.at_xpath('//meta[@name ="trackmetrics_verification"])['content']
```